# Conversion failed in SQL statement in C #

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem trying to execute a SQL statement, I explain I want to show information depending on a number that I send per parameter, but at the time of executing my query I get thrown the following exception:

[image]

My statement is the following and where the exception is thrown:

```
public List<cDireccionEmbarque> obtenerDireccion(string customer_id)
{
    DataFramework.Query q = new DataFramework.Query()
                .SelAs("CUSTOMER_ID", "ca.CUSTOMER_ID")
                .SelAs("SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO", "ca.ADDR_NO")
                .SelAs("NAME", "ca.NAME")
                .FromAs("ca", "CUST_ADDRESS")
                .Where("CUSTOMER_ID", customer_id)
                .OrderBy("ca.NAME");
    return Tools.Connection.Fima.ExecList<cDireccionEmbarque>(q);
}
```

In this method I declare a string variable to receive the value of the following code

```
opedidoMigradoLinea.listaEmbarque = obtenerDireccion(opedidoMigradoLinea.CUSTOMER_ID);
```

in that line of code the .CUSTOMER_ID returns a number to me, already debugging my code in this case it returns a 5, and that CUSTOMER_ID I get it from my class and I have it as follows

```
public string CUSTOMER_ID { get; set; }
```

and when executing my statement in SQL Server I get the same error

[image]

But at the time of putting single quotes to my return value (5) if you give me the information

[image]

What I want to know is how to solve that problem in my method where I make that statement if they require more explanation I will be aware

Comment: Perhaps the customer id is an int in the database. Have you tried using an int for the customer id?

Comment: @Silvermind in my database my customer_id is nvarchar

Comment: `249-1` is definitely not an `int`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace customer_id with single quoted customer_id

```
$"'{customer_id}'"
```